# Select random element from Map, with non-uniform distribution

Tags: haskell

I have a map `m` (using `import Data.Map`), and I want to select two elements from it randomly. So far I have tried this in GHCI (which doesn't work):

```
> :module System.Random
> -- define my map in "m", not important here
> let myrand a = getStdRandom $ randomR (0, a - 1)
> elemAt (myrand (size m)) m
```

I get an error: `Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type 'IO Int'`.

So, first question, how can I make this work (can I convert an `IO Int` into an `Int`?)? Eventually I want a function to extract two different values from the map.

And, second question, how can I make elements with "lesser keys" be more likely to be selected? Right now, if my code worked, it would just select an element with a uniform distribution. I want a simple way of saying "element A, with key lower than element B, has a higher chance of being selected". I have no idea how to proceed here, I tried looking at [some documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.6.2/docs/Data-Random-Distribution.html), but I have no idea how to make that work (or if it's even useful to me).

Comment: "can I convert an IO Int into an Int?" no.  You're expressing a nondeterministic operation; it's going to have to be in `IO` or in a randomness monad.

Comment: As far as the distribution goes, you're going to have to pick an exact mathematical distribution for what you mean by "element A has a higher chance of being selected."

Comment: If you want to assign probabilities to each element based solely on their *position* in the `Map`, and not their *values*, then you will need to use `findIndex :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Int` or convert the `Map` to an ordered container first, like a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select elements of the `Map` based on their position in the `Map`, it will be easier to first convert to a list, because a `Map` is an unordered container.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M 
import Control.Monad.Random (fromList, MonadRandom) 

sampleAscending :: (MonadRandom m, Ord k) => M.Map k a -> m a 
sampleAscending m = fromList $ zip (map snd $ M.toAscList m) [l,l-1..]
  where l = fromIntegral $ M.size m
```

Since you didn't specify *which* distribution, I just picked something simple (`[l,l-1..]`). The `fromList` function has type `MonadRandom m => [(a, Rational)] -> m a`. The first element of the tuple in the input list in the candidate element, and the second element of the tuple is the probability of that item occuring. The `MonadRandom` interface takes care of the rest for you!

To convince you this indeed works, here is a little test function:

```
import Control.Monad 
import Text.Printf 

testSample :: (Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> IO () 
testSample strIn = do 
  let m0 = M.fromList $ zip [1..] strIn 
      len = 10000 :: Float 
  str <- replicateM (round len) (sampleAscending m0) 
  forM_ strIn $ \c -> 
    printf "%s occured with probability %f\n"
      (show c) ((fromIntegral.length.filter(==c)$ str)/len)
```

and

```
>testSample "abc"
'a' occured with probability 0.5044
'b' occured with probability 0.3281
'c' occured with probability 0.1675

>testSample "abcdefg"
'a' occured with probability 0.2473
'b' occured with probability 0.2192
'c' occured with probability 0.1814
'd' occured with probability 0.1339
'e' occured with probability 0.1112
'f' occured with probability 0.0687
'g' occured with probability 0.0383
```

Comment: This is incredible, it works! Apparently I need to go to the books and really learn what a monad is.